# Calling another function of a class from within the same class, when this refers to something else

Tags: node.js, events, ecmascript-6

We have this code:

```
class Example {
    constructor(num) {
        this.a = num;
        this.eventEmitter = null;
    }
    doSomething() {
        // This doesn't work because 'this' will refer to the emitter.
        this.a += 1;
    }
    registerEvents(eventEmitter){
        this.eventEmitter = eventEmitter;
        eventEmitter.on('event', this.doSomething);
    }
}
```

and we want to bind it to an event emitter, like this:

```
function ExampleUser() {
    const EventEmitter = require('events');
    eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
    var reactor = new Example(1);
    reactor.registerEvents(eventEmitter);
    eventEmitter.emit('event');
}
```

The problem is, that when `doSomething()` is called, just like supposed, the this refers to the emitter, not to the Example object. Therefore, it cannot update `this.a` as we would like.

Help?

Comment: have you tried to change this.doSomething.bind(this) in registerEvents?

Answer (score 1):

You need to `bind` your event listener to your `Example` instance:

```
registerEvents(eventEmitter){
    this.eventEmitter = eventEmitter;
    eventEmitter.on('event', this.doSomething.bind(this));
}
```